# What does the intersection between given surface and a surface that contains the y-axis look like?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, contest-math, education

So I was trying to do this exercise, but when I thought I figured it out it seems to be that my answer is wrong, could anyone tell me why?

question: Given the surface $S$: $z=x^2-1$ and a surface that contains the $y$-axis. What does the intersection look like with the plane $S$?

- hyperbola
- parabola
- ellipse
- straight line(s)

**My reasoning**
So I started out by drawing $S$ in a $xz$-plane which gave me a parabola. So then I reasoned that if I took a plane e.g. y = 5 then the intersection would still give me a parabola, but somehow the answer is straight line(s). Why is this so, becaus when I put it in GeoGebra it also tells me that it should be a parabola. Is there something wrong with my understanding of the question? PLease let met know.
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are lots of different surfaces that contain the $y$-axis, but the plane $y=5$ isn't one of them - it's orthogonal to the $y$-axis. The $y$-axis is the 1-dimensional set of points satisfying $x=z=0$.

Comment: Also, do you mean a *plane* containing the $y$-axis or really just any surface?

Comment: @Karl thank you for your response. But I don't think I truly know what it means for a surface that contains the y-axis. I get that the $y$-axis is the set of points on the $y$-axis itself (so when $x$ and $y$ equals zero). But why isn't this the case for $y=5$ because it contains a point on the $y$-axis namely  5. So why doesn't it hold? Maybe its a stupid question, but I'm trying to understand. And could you maybe give a surface that holds for this type of question, maybe that would make it more clear for me. Thx

Comment: "Contains $A$" in this context means "is a superset of $A$" which means "contains *every point* of $A$". An example of a plane that contains the $y$-axis is the set of points satisfying $z=2x$, because if a point $(x,y,z)$ satisfies $x=z=0$, then it also satisfies $z=2x$.

Comment: @Karl Thank you for your help!